# How wait copy process on msbuild

Tags: msbuild

I create example to copy file from one folder to another (use msbuild). I try check after copy, if file was moved? But message still show, that files didn't moved. But when I see on folder, files was moved successful. So how it's fix?

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
    <PathPackage>C:\Users\test\Desktop\test\1\*.txt</PathPackage>
    <Files>C:\Users\test\Desktop\test\2\*.*</Files>
    </PropertyGroup>
        <ItemGroup>
            <Packages Include="$(PathPackage)"/>
            <FilesOnFolder Include="$(Files)"/>
        </ItemGroup>

        <Target Name="B">
            <Message Importance="normal" Text="Package before copy:@(Packages)"/>
            <CreateItem Include="@(Packages)">
                <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="FilesToMove" />
            </CreateItem>
            <Copy
                SourceFiles="@(Packages)"
                DestinationFolder="C:\Users\test\Desktop\test\2"
            />

             <Delete Files="@(Packages)" />
            <Message Importance="normal" Text="Package after package:@(Packages)"/><!--It's full! -->
            <Message Importance="normal" Text="Destination Folder:@(FilesOnFolder)"/>  <!--It's empty! -->
        </Target>   
    </Project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in ItemGroup. It need write inside target.

Comment: I was looking for this answer for a looooong time :)